# Can I use an EVGA OC utility on a ZOTAC GPU?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, overclocking

EVGA has a very nice comprehensive utility while ZOTAC.. not so much. The specs for the two cards (EVGA vs ZOTAC) are not far off (660 Ti) so it seems plausible that one utility would work for the other unless there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use MSI afterburner too, they're basically the same thing anyway, and yes, I've used them before, cross-gpu.

Comment: Thought I'd add that the ZOTAC software caused display driver failures every boot up and often glitched the PC into rebooting. Made the screen all "rainbowy".